# See the size of the specific document in a specific branch of a repository

Tags: graphql, github-graphql

I want to determine the size of the file "foo" in the master branch of johndoe's "boo" repository.

Any suggestion?

I am using https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer to make the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query can be used to determine the size of a given document located in a branch of a repository that belongs to another person.

```
{
  user(login:"userName"){
    repository(name:"boo") {
      object(expression: "master:foo") {
        ... on Blob {
          byteSize
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do I have an option to see if it is binary or not?

Comment: add ", isBinary " after byteSize.